# SlowCheetah not previewing transform on deployment profile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, nuget-package, msdeploy

I have a webjob that I am looking to transform the app.config on.  I have installed SlowCheetah and it works fine with a transform for release and debug versions.  However if I try to use it with the transformations for specific deployment profiles to azure, I get nothing on the preview transform.  The option is there, but nothing happens when I click it.  This also means that the standard app.config is applied on deployment.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, I have installed the SlowCheetah and test it in my side, it works well.

So I suggest you could follow below steps to reinstall the SlowCheetah and try again.

1.Download [it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) and install.

2.Add the app.config transform to your project, for example app.Debug.config and app.Release.config

3.Open your *.csproj file and you will find these lines (depending on the name and number of transformation you want :

```
<None Include="App.Release.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
</None>
<None Include="App.Debug.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
</None>
```

above these lines :

```
<None Include="App.config">
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>
```

4. Reload your project and it should work.

The result is like this:

[image]

---

Update:

I guess you don't add the new build configuration to your web job application.

So you will find the preview is not work well.

I suggest you could follow below steps to add new build configuration.

1.Open configuration manager

[image]

2.Add new confiuration

[image]

3.Add transform

[image]

4.Preview

[image]

Comment: Hi Brando,thanks for looking at this.  Have you got it working on anything other than debug or release transformations?  I'd like to deploy to a 3rd server for testing that runs on a different SQL database to live or dev.  It looks like I should be able to do a transform based on the deployment profile name e.g. "Web Deploy - UAT"

Comment: I guess you don't add the build configuration. See my update answer, you will find how to do it.

Comment: Ah, got ya, I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on.  Thanks

Comment: You are a star this worked a treat.  I was being thrown off by the auto added transformations when you choose add.  Thanks for your help